# jQuery slider image centering advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

I'm looking for a slider which you can have a background image e.g. 1920px wide 400px high, but the main content of the slider is something like 1000px, the slider will automatically scale down until it gets to the center of the image? A little like http://www.morganstanley.com/.

I've had a look at JSSOR but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Please place your slider in the following wrapper,

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; background-color: #003399; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 50%; width: 5000px; text-align: center; margin-left: -2500px;">
        <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
        <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; ...;">
            ...
        </div>
        <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
    </div>
</div>
```

You will get get an example as http://www.jssor.com/testcase/auto-center-slider-with-no-scale.source.html